# Initialize Access Type - uninitialized unconstraind allocation not allowed

Tags: pointers, ada

I'm currently struggeling a bit when trying to initialize an array access.
I've got the following in my generic package specification:

```
generic
    type Item_Type is private;
    with function "+"(Left: Item_Type; Right: Item_Type) return Item_Type;
package Parallel_Algorithms is

    type Array_Type is array(Natural range <>) of Item_Type;
    type Array_Access_Type is access all Array_Type;
    ...
end Parallel_Algorithms;
```

where `Item_Type` should be the type of my generic package. I would now like to instantiate the Array_Access_Type in another procedure since I need to pass it to a function also specified in the package. The package is instantiated in the following way:

```
package Natural_Parallel is new Parallel_Algorithms(Item_Type => Natural,
                                                    "+"       => "+");
```

I found some forum thread where the answer was basically like that:

```
Arr_Acc: Array_Access_Type := new Array_Type;
```

However I get the following error I don't quite understand:

```
uninitialized unconstrained allocation not allowed
qualified expression or constraint with array bounds required
```

What is the correct way to instantiate the access type with some values inside of the array for later use?

Comment: `new Array_Type` creates a new array and returns the pointer to it. A new array ... of what size? At which point the error messages make sense ... you must specify the size of an array when creating it! for example, `new Array_Type(1 .. 10)`. If you want something unconstrained, that grows when you nee it, use something from `Ada.Containers` instead.

Comment: After reading the reference about 20 more times I finally got the error and it makes total sense in the end. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Be certain to check whether or not you actually need the double indirection here: compilers will arrange for arrays to be passed by reference, not by copy, irrespective of the parameter mode (**in** or **out**). Also, you can drop `all` from the definition of `Array_Access_Type` if you do not take the  `'Access` of some stack allocated array, or of an array declared at library level.